# Something is still looking for jquery 1.3

Tags: jquery, telerik

I upgraded from JQuery 1.3 to 1.4.1, but now I get an exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
Message="Specified file does not exist: \"~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js\"."
Source="Telerik.Web.Mvc"
```

in the call to Telerik's ScriptRegistrarBuilder.Render().  But I am not referring to Jquery 1.3 anywhere in my code!  If I do a global recursive `*.*` search on jquery-1.3.2 I come up with nothing.  Where could that rogue reference be coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade!  ServicePack 2 for Telerik supports jQuery 1.4:

[Service Pack 2 for Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC released](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-01-20/service_pack_2_for_telerik_extensions_for_asp_net_mvc_released.aspx)

Comment: Absolutely! Upgrading is the only solution if you want to use jQuery 1.4 and Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks! It works with JQuery 1.4.  However, if I use 1.4.1 it complains that it cannot find 1.4!

Answer (score 0):

Not positive, but it's probably referenced directly in Telerik's code (in which case, you're going to need it no matter what).

Answer (score 0):

As Nick Craver said you need to upgrade to [Service Pack 2](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-01-20/service_pack_2_for_telerik_extensions_for_asp_net_mvc_released.aspx). The version you are currently using is based on jQuery 1.3.2 and simply avoiding the automatic inclusion of jquery-1.3.2.js won't be enough as jQuery 1.4 is not 100% compatible with jQuery 1.3.2.